# How do I use the same card on multiple lists in Trello?

Tags: trello

How do I create a card in Trello that I can then include on two different lists?

That would be helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no way to do this in Trello.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively ([yet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24252/809)) but you can clone the card in Chrome with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl?hl=en-GB and then move it.