# Can I duplicate a card on the same board (to split its content) in Trello?

Tags: trello

Moving a card from one Trello board to another has been implemented recently but I am still missing some basic "duplicate card" functionality. Is it possible to duplicate or clone a card on the same board as its original?

In my use case for some software development, I would like some sub-functionalities (listed in a card checklist) stay in my project backlog while others on the same card are brought to the next step toward life.

I am not asking for some split function inside Trello, which I guess would be relatively heavy to implement. Duplicate function would be convenient enough, as I would just have to delete checklist elements according to my reorganization instead of (currently) having to manually clone the card and all information inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the clone functionality implemented in Trello itself, you can use the [Trello Clone Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl)

Answer (score 5):

Good news! The "copy/clone/ template boards, lists, cards, and checklists" card is in the <strike>'Next Up'</strike> "In Progress" column on the public Trello development board, https://trello.com/c/LIqasVwP; please vote it up, work ought to start on it soon!

Comment: This shipped several months ago, if you happen to be looking at this now.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate a card by selecting "Copy" in the "Actions" section on any card. (see [Trello Help](https://help.trello.com/article/802-copying-cards-lists-or-boards))